# installing frePPLe library for Python

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to launch frePPLE software without a user interface. To do that I need to install a frePPLe library for Python. I found the documentation here https://frepple.org/docs/6.10/installation-guide/python-module.php how I can install it, however, I do not understand where to find **`frepple.pyd`** file, which is described at the first point of the installation guide. I also tried to find this file here https://github.com/frePPLe/frepple, but I was failed again. I'm using frePPLe 6.15 version, it would be very helpful if somebody knows how to install this library. The installation guide about 6.15 version of frePPLe is located here https://frepple.org/docs/6.15/installation-guide/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved, for more information visit https://github.com/frePPLe/frepple/discussions/417

Comment: Hi @makarovm, please include a brief explanation of the solution. The links are not always reliable and it makes it easier for other stackoverflowers who encounter similar problem.